# Background colour behind Title and Icon of BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, bottomnavigationview

How do I remove the background colour behind **title** and **icon** of a BottomNavigationView?

Currently I am using `Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView` as its base theme like this

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.BottomNav" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryActive</item>
</style>
```

However there are unsightly backgrounds behind the title and the icon when clicked on (ripple)

[image: Image Result of Style]

How do I remove them?
Is there a style item to target the icon/title directly so i can just set their background to transparent?

**EDIT 1**
Here is my xml layout code

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BottomNav"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Comment: You can just use style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored" and you can see here what style attributes you get with them https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: I have tried it, but it looks bad with dark theme as the app bar is not coloured.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by

#### Removing the `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BottomNav"` line

It is fixed somehow.